# What is the purpose of the TARGET_NAME generator expression?

Tags: cmake

In the [CMake documentation describing generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#output-expressions) there is this paragraph:

> `$<TARGET_NAME:...>`
>
> Marks `...` as being the name of a target. **This is required if exporting targets to multiple dependent export sets**. The `...` must be a literal name of a target- it may not contain generator expressions.

I am trying to understand the highlighted part.

First I want to see if I understand correctly the notion of *dependent export sets*. If target `B` depends on target `A` and if *export set* `EXP_A` contains target `A` and *export set* `EXP_B` contains target `B`, then the *export set* `EXP_B` is dependent on the *export set* `EXP_A`. Is this correct?

Why is `$<TARGET_NAME:...>` "**required if exporting targets to multiple dependent export sets**"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what they mean by "multiple dependent export sets". I looked at their test suite and couldn't find anything like that. It's confusing to me, too.

However, I *can* give you an example where `$<TARGET_NAME:...>` actually does something. Consider:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test)

add_library(define_a INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(define_a INTERFACE A)

add_library(define_a_tgt INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(define_a_tgt INTERFACE "A_TGT=\"$<TARGET_NAME:define_a>\"")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(TARGETS define_a define_a_tgt EXPORT test)
install(
  EXPORT test
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/test
  FILE test-config.cmake
  NAMESPACE test::
)
```

Here, we have two silly `INTERFACE` libraries. The first, `define_a`, simply propagates `-DA` to the target linking to it. The second, `define_a_tgt` adds a definition of `A_TGT` such that it is equal to the *string* containing the name of the target `define_a`.

In the build interface, this will expand to simply `define_a`, but after exporting it, CMake will replace `$<TARGET_NAME:define_a>` with `test::define_a` (on account of the `NAMESPACE` argument to `install(EXPORT)`).

This is a bit contrived, but it does show an instance where CMake is not already aware that a target is being named (it transforms `target_link_libraries` targets automatically, without this genex). Another instance is *inside* other generator expressions (even in `target_link_libraries`).